# Adicionar um link de URL a uma classe CSS via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

É possível adicionar um link de url à minha classe CSS via JS?

Porque não posso editar meu arquivo HTML.

Eu tenho esse CSS para mudar meu logotipo quando rola:

```
.she-header .logo img {
visibility: hidden;
    }

.she-header .logo {
    content:url(https://example.com/Logo2.png) !important;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 101px;
    width: 185px;
    }
```

Mas quando ele rola pra baixo eu perco o link do URL para minha home.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Tem uma maneira de fazer isso com JS?

Comment: Como assim amigo vc perde o link? Tem alguma tag `<a>` envolta do logo? Ela tem algum ID por acaso ou alguma classe só aplicada nesse link? Não ficou claro o problema...

Answer (score 1):

Não da para entender bem o que vc quer. Mas o que acredito é quer é trocar um `href` de um link...

Então vc pode pegar o `<a>` que vc quer pelo `ID` ou `Classe` e trocar o valor do `href` como no exemplo abaixo.

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a.ouClasse"); 
a.href = "http://link.novo"
```

```html
<a href="http://link.antigo" id="idDoLink" class="ouClasse">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Via JQuery fica da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".logo").attr({style: "content:url(https://example.com/Logo2.png)" });
}
```